# Using resource Id and apiVersion in Azure Bicep modules

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-bicep

I currently have one large .bicep file called main.bicep that I am working on modularizing. Specifically I have been working on moving the Cosmos resources into a file of its own called cosmos-db.bicep and consuming it in main.bicep.

cosmos-db.bicep

```
// Parameters

param cosmosAccountName string
param databaseName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param appTags object
param subnetFunctionName string
param ipRules array
param vnetName string
param cosmosDbName string

// Variables

var dealDataContainerName = 'deal'
var refDataContainerName = 'refdata'
var userProfileContainerName = 'userprofile'

// Cosmos DB Container info to be looped over
var cosmosContainers = [
  {
    name: userProfileContainerName
    id: 'userprofile'
    partitionKey: '/userId'
  }
  {
    name: refDataContainerName
    id: 'refdata'
    partitionKey: '/partKey'
  }
  {
    name: dealDataContainerName
    id: 'deal'
    partitionKey: '/dealId'
  }
]

// Resource References

resource subnetFunction 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets@2020-08-01' existing = {
  name: subnetFunctionName
}

resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2020-08-01' existing = {
  name: vnetName
}

// Resources

// Cosmos DB Account
resource cosmos 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts@2020-06-01-preview' = {
  name: cosmosAccountName
  location: location
  tags: appTags
  kind: 'GlobalDocumentDB'
  identity: {
    type: 'None'
  }
  properties: {
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled' //TODO - ulp.
    enableAutomaticFailover: true
    enableMultipleWriteLocations: true
    isVirtualNetworkFilterEnabled: true // Suggested to be set as false by MS
    virtualNetworkRules: [
      {
        id: subnetFunction.id
        ignoreMissingVNetServiceEndpoint: false
      }
    ]
    disableKeyBasedMetadataWriteAccess: false
    enableFreeTier: false
    enableAnalyticalStorage: false
    createMode: 'Default'
    databaseAccountOfferType: 'Standard'
    consistencyPolicy: {
      defaultConsistencyLevel: 'Session'
      maxIntervalInSeconds: 5
      maxStalenessPrefix: 100
    }
    locations: [
      {
        locationName: location
        failoverPriority: 0
        isZoneRedundant: true
      }
      {
        locationName: 'Central US'
        failoverPriority: 1
        isZoneRedundant: true
      }
    ]
    cors: []
    capabilities: []
    ipRules: ipRules
    backupPolicy: {
      type: 'Periodic'
      periodicModeProperties: {
        backupIntervalInMinutes: 240
        backupRetentionIntervalInHours: 8
      }
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    virtualNetwork
  ]
}

// Cosmos SQL Database
resource cosmosdb 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases@2020-04-01' = {
  name: cosmosDbName
  // parent: cosmos
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: databaseName
    }
    options: {
      throughput: 400
    }
  }
}

// Cosmos Containers
resource cosmosContainerUser 'Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers@2021-06-15' = [for container in cosmosContainers: {
  name: container.name
  parent: cosmosdb
  properties: {
    resource: {
      id: container.id
      indexingPolicy: {
        indexingMode: 'consistent'
        automatic: true
        includedPaths:[
          {
            path: '/*'
          }
        ]
        excludedPaths: [
          {
            path: '/"_etag"/?'
          }
        ]
      }
      partitionKey: {
        kind: 'Hash'
        paths: [
          container.partitionKey
        ]
      } 
      conflictResolutionPolicy: {
        mode: 'LastWriterWins'
        conflictResolutionPath: '/_ts'
      }
    }
  }
}]

output resource object = cosmos
```

main.bicep

```
module cosmos '../../../cicd/bicep/modules/datastore/cosmos-db.bicep' = {
  name: cosmosAccountName
  params: {
    cosmosAccountName: cosmosAccountName
    cosmosDbName: cosmosDbName
    databaseName: databaseName
    appTags: appTags
    subnetFunctionName: '${virtualNetwork.name}/function'
    vnetName: vnetName
    ipRules: [for address in ipaddresses: {
      ipAddressOrRange: '${address.CIDR}'
    }]
  }
}
```

This code works and creates a Cosmos account, one Cosmos database, and three Cosmos containers. Although the Cosmos deployments pass, the overall pipeline fails because of my key vault secret resource.

main.bicep

```
// Key Vault Secret
resource kvsecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2019-09-01' = if (deployDB || deployKV) {
  name: '${keyVault.name}/databaseConnectionString'
  dependsOn: [
    keyVault
  ]
  properties: {
    value: listConnectionStrings(cosmos.id, cosmos.apiVersion).connectionStrings[0].connectionString
    attributes: {
      nbf: 1617093384
      enabled: true
      exp: 1680161784
    }
  }
}
```

I get an error from the `listConnectionString()` function saying: `The type "module" does not contain property "apiVersion". Available properties include "name", "outputs".`

In an attempt to get rid of this error I tried to change the values to `listConnectionString(cosmos.name, '2020-06-01-preview')` which gives an error saying:

```
"The api-version '2020-06-01-preview' is invalid. The supported versions are '2021-04-01,2021-01-01,2020-10-01,2020-09-01,2020-08-01,2020-07-01,2020-06-01,2020-05-01,2020-01-01,2019-11-01,2019-10-01,2019-09-01,2019-08-01,2019-07-01,2019-06-01,2019-05-10,2019-05-01,2019-03-01,2018-11-01,2018-09-01,2018-08-01,2018-07-01,2018-06-01,2018-05-01,2018-02-01,2018-01-01,2017-08-01,2017-06-01,2017-05-10,2017-05-01,2017-03-01,2016-09-01,2016-07-01,2016-06-01,2016-02-01,2015-11-01,2015-01-01,2014-04-01-preview,2014-04-01,2014-01-01,2013-03-01,2014-02-26,2014-04'.\"
```

I then tried to change `2020-06-01-preview` to `2020-06-01` which returned an error of:
`"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourcegroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/gbt-nprod-iac-eastus2-dealservice-cosmos/listConnectionStrings?api-version=2020-06-01'.\"`

I know the issue is because a module doesn't contain the id and apiVersion properties so I then tried to use the outputs from the resource group.

I added to following line to cosmos-db.bicep:

```
output apiVersion string = cosmos.apiVersion
```

And also added the following to main.bicep:

```
var apiVersion = cosmos.outputs.apiVersion

// Key Vault Secret
resource kvsecret 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets@2019-09-01' = if (deployDB || deployKV) {
...
  properties: {
    value: listConnectionStrings(cosmos.name, apiVersion).connectionStrings[0].connectionString
    attributes: {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

This resulted in a different error saying:
 `This expression is being used in an argument of the function "listConnectionStrings", which requires a value that can be calculated at the start of the deployment. You are referencing a variable which cannot be calculated at the start ("apiVersion" -> "cosmos"). Properties of cosmos which can be calculated at the start include "name".`

My question is, is there another way to retrieve the Cosmos connection string for the key vault secret? If not, how can I correctly add Cosmos' API version to this `listConnectionStrings()` function?

Comment: I think you should use `cosmos.outputs.resource.id`,  `cosmos.outputs.resource.apiVersion` if you define `output resource object = cosmos` and you module name is `cosmos`.